# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in parallel.For is not working

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, monodevelop

I am new to Monodevelop as well as UBUNTU and now I am trying to develop an desktop application using c# to investigate the .Net parallelism. I am stuck with one issue when I use Parallel.For loop. As of I read on the Internet, Dispatcher.beginInvoke will delegate the work done by worker thread to the UI thread.

The article also says that if you don't use dispatcher it will through an error for the desktop applications. but it still working fine for me. I am not understanding what is happening here. (here is the link I am using -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx)

Here is the code:

```
Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
{
   var result = SumRootN(i);
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
   textBlock1.Text += "root " + i.ToString() + " " +
   result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)
   , null);
});
```

If i take out "this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>" statement still it is working as expected, but according to the link I mentioned above it should not work.

Details:

Monodevelop Version - monodevelop 2.8.6.3+dfsg-2
Ubuntu Version - 12.4

Comment: Dispatcher is part of the WPF framework which is not implemented in Mono. What kind of GUI framework are you trying to use? It is probably Windows Forms and then here is the method you are interested in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I did not understand what you mean "What kind of GUI framework are you trying to use?" can you please elaborate it to me.

Comment: Look here: http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

Answer (score 0):

It might also be that `Parallel.For` is only giving you a single thread (do you have a single core CPU?) - then it would run in the same thread that it was created and wouldn't fail without Invoke. Also, in some cases you *can* get away with updating UI from background thread, but you can't count on it - it might break later.

Comment: NO, I can run four threads at a time. and also i can see that when i execute my program all cores will be working and it is double faster than the normal For loop